# Android: Spinners loose their values when I add dynamically new ListView entries on click of spinner item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing android apps. In my apps having two activities, first activity is displaying list and in second activity having spinner and listview in the same activity and when user click on the item from spinner the listview will be displayed. when user navigate from first activity to second activity then spinner is properly populated with listview. but problem is that after listview displayed properly then spinner item was blank. I don't know where i am doing wrong. Please anybody have solution.

Here i am posting few code of Second Activity

```
public class ProjectDetailActivity extends SherlockListActivity {

private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_detail);

        //get spinner item from server when user comes from first activity.
        new LoadPhaseData().execute();

        //Listener for Phase spinner

        projSpinnerPhase.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                                    //get listview when user click item from spinner 
                new LoadPhaseData().execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }           
        }); 
        //this adapter for listview when click item from spinner
        ListAdapter phaseAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                list2, R.layout.phase_avail_list_item, 
                new String[] {PHASE_NAME}, new int[] 
                        {R.id.phaseName});
        setListAdapter(phaseAdapter);


    }
    private class LoadPhaseData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Here I am calling web service for spinner and listview
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //following adapter for spinner item
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            projSpinnerPhase.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are assigning new Adapter to the `Spinner` with new values while you are adding new rows to `Spinner`. Spinner losses its previous row along with the previous data and get another Adapter with new data rows.  You need to append these value to the existing data-holder (may be an array or ArrayList) and then call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

You need to move ArrayList to the class-level, (i.e make it class field) then while you have downloaded data. just append new data to the `list` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I declared list as class field and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after projSpinnerPhase.setAdapter(dataAdapter) but this time spinner data displaying properly and listview is displaying but after some seconds listview was blank. can you help me?

Comment: please check you are using different ArrayList for ListView and Spinner.

Comment: yes i am using two different ArrayList for ListView and Spinner but I am not understand what do you want to say?

Comment: if you have time please see updated question. I wrote comment properly. now what happen is, spinner and listview displaying properly

Comment: now what happen is, spinner and listview displaying properly but web service continuously calling. i am appreciated for your help

Comment: this is because when you set new adapter to Spinner, it automatically calls `onItemSelected()` . *(This is default behavior.)* as I already told you don't create new Adapter, just create it once in `onCreat()` and update your ArrayList only from `onPostExecute()`. because when you create new adapter, it automatically selects 0th index of Spinner and your `OnItemSelectedListener` is called, and again your webservice is called and this is leading you to infinite calls. Hope you got my point.